# Do i need to enable billing and actually be billed to build an app for Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm developer. Do I need to enable billing and actually be billed to build an app for Google Cloud Storage? Do they have a sandbox of some kind or some trial period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Google does offer a starter pack program, which gives you $2,000 in credits - $1K for App Engine and $1K for Compute Engine and Cloud Storage.

To take advantage of this program, visit [this site](http://cloud.google.com/starterpack) and use promo code **macoh-in**

Comment: What does it mean "in credits"? Will I have to pay for it in the end anyway?

Comment: You still have to enable billing for your account but the first $1K for App Engine and $1K for Compute Engine and Storage are free of charge (if you take advantage of this program).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, billing is required to be able to create a bucket, which is step 1 for building anything on Google Cloud Storage. The good news is that if you don't use much space, your bill will probably be less than a dollar per month.  You might want to check out the [price sheet](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/cloud-storage) for a clearer picture of what you'll be charged.

Comment: Bro I dont have any International Debit/Credit card, its not easy to get one here, how do I try cloud storage ( create/edit,delete bucket/object)?
Is there any public bucket or object that I can try for testing app?